# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This is my code line throwing error

```
$get("Panel1").style.visibility= "visible";
```

This line works well on normal page .But whenever using it on child page which owns a master page it throws the error as "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined". I am a great beginner to javascript . I am using this on Asp.Net 3.5 .Any one know this issue before .

Comment: Are you sure "Panel1" is the id of the element? In a File>New project with no modifications, putting a Panel into a child form (I *think* that's what you're describing) will result in the element id of "MainContent_Panel1", where the ContentPlaceHolderId is prepended to preclude naming conflicts. Try doing a View->Source and see what the id is associated with the div that gets generated.

Comment: @jim-oneil  : Thanks for the reply . I am checked with that exactly matching ..

Comment: but it didn't match :) as you found when following @Aristos fix... I should have been more explicit/detailed, but glad you got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably because you do not use the rendered id, that is change if you use the same panel on dipper page. And because you do not use the correct id, the `$get()` part return  the `null or undefined`. Change your code to:

```
$get("<%=Panel1.ClientID%>").style.visibility= "visible";
```

and render the panel1 id as it will final be on the html page.

What you should have to solve it alone: You could on the page to see the "view page source" from your browser utility and see if the `Panel1` id exist on your html struct, there you can find what was the correct id and the reason that was not found. So the point here is that we look the html rendered page to find out whats going wrong with the scripts.

Comment: Thanks Aristos ...It's the fix